# Payment gateway with third party redirects in magento2

Tags: magento2, payment-gateway, third-party-module

Payment gateway with third party redirects in magento2 not working

```
public function placeRequest(TransferInterface $transferObject)
    { 
        $response = $this->generateResponseForCode(
            $this->getResultCode(
                $transferObject
            )
        );
        //header("location:https://www.google.com/");

        // $CustomRedirectionUrl = $this->_url->getUrl('https://www.google.com/');
        // $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($CustomRedirectionUrl)->sendResponse();



        $this->logger->debug(
            [
                'request' => $transferObject->getBody(),
                'response' => $response
            ]
        );

        return $response;
    }
```

Comment: Can you share your module here? You need to fix js stuff.

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/tree/master/sample-module-payment-gateway

Answer (score 0):

[You can check here](https://github.com/oxipay/oxipay-magento-2.x/blob/master/Oxipay/OxipayPaymentGateway/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/oxipay_gateway.js)

Specially **redirectAfterPlaceOrder: false,**

```
afterPlaceOrder: function () {
                window.location.replace(url.build('oxipay/checkout/index'));
            },
```